# Display:none doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grey out the screen, then make it gradually disappear when I click anywhere on the screen.

I have this code in jQuery:

```
$('#clickme').on("click", function() 
{
    $('#screen').css(
    {
        'display': 'block',
        'width':$(document).width(),
        'height':$(document).height()
    });

    $('#screen').animate(
    {
        opacity: '0.7',
    }, 1000, function() 
    {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

$("#screen").on("click", function() 
{
    $(this).animate(
    {
        'display': 'none',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 1000, function() 
    {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

It works one time, but the problem is the screen.on("click") works for the opacity, but doesn't work for the display. I don't get why. Please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation only works on numbers. `display` does not take numbers, so what you need to do is

```
$("#screen").on("click", function() 
{
    $(this).animate( {
        'opacity': 0
    }, 1000, function()  {
         $(this).css('display','none');
    });
});
```

First, make it eaze to 0% opacity, *then* remove it.

Answer (score 3):

This is because display is not a numeric value, from http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, 
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be 
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality

Answer (score 2):

From the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate):

> *"most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality"*

Since `display: none` isn't a numeric property, it can't be animated. Instead, try hiding it as a callback to the animation:

```
 var screen = $(this); // save a variable for the closure in the callback   
 screen.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function() { screen.hide(); });
```

Note also that I changed the value of opacity to be numeric, and not a string with a numeric value. This might not matter, but it's good practice =)

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TxtJ/) that demonstrates the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animation does not work for display: rules.
```

Because it does not have a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Display doesn't have a numeric value hence cannot be used in jquery animations.

Add `$(this).hide();` to hide the element when animations is complete to the callback function:

```
$("#screen").on("click", function() 
{
    $(this).animate(
    {
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 1000, function() 
    {
        // Animation complete.
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that opacity is a numeric value while display is not numeric.

You should have a look at fadeOut that does what you want:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/